# matlab plot eliminate axis but giving info on the ticks step

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, normalize

I have the following problem: my plots should be **normalized in order to don't show any absolute values**. Therefore a simple method to do it is taking the axis out of the figure. But in order to understand something on the difference between two curves i need an info on the **step between two ticks**.
Like: no values on y-Ticks but then between third and fourth Tick a double arrow and text saying 2 g/kWh as in the example here (but with a correct arrow and maybe the info on the left 90° rotated):

---

^
| 2 g/kWh
|
v

---

How can i do it in Matlab? Any idea?
Here a sample code of my plot:

```
figure(1)
hold on
grid on
plot([10,25,50,75,100],[120,134,145,167,180],'-x','LineWidth',2)
xlabel('Load - [%]')
ylabel('BSFC - [g/kWh]')
legend('Normal Conditions','location','best')
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can't you divide everything by the maximal value to normalize?

Comment: No, I need exactely that way as shown in the answer here down, only placed between two ticks and with a nice arrow

Comment: ok so if the answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the green mark below it. Thanks

Comment: so is this what you wanted??

Answer (score 0):

What if you add this line as the ylabel:

```
AxisString = sprintf('<---  --->\n 2g/kWh\n')
```

so you code would be:

```
figure(1)
hold on
grid on
plot([10,25,50,75,100],[120,134,145,167,180],'-x','LineWidth',2)
xlabel('Load - [%]')
%ylabel('BSFC - [g/kWh]')
legend('Normal Conditions','location','best')

AxisString = sprintf('<---  --->\n 2g/kWh\n')

set(gca,'YTickLabel',[]) % Remove YTick labels.
ylabel(AxisString)
```

Giving this:

[image]